# Как сделать скриншот всего кода в PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, скриншот

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать скриншот в PyCharm? То есть не просто скриншот, а полный захват всего кода. Наподобие того, как это делает дополнение FireShot для мозиллы. А именно захват всей страницы и сохранение в jpg или в другой формат. А то неудобно вырезать обычными виндовскими ножницами. Они лишь вырезают то, что на экране. А код длиннее высоты монитора.
Мне, просто, нужно нарисовать там стрелочки всякие и всё такое. Или может быть в самом Pycharm'е есть рисовалка? Хотя, вряд ли.
Спасибо!

Comment: Вы можете оформить [ответ на свой вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), и это приветствуется сообществом. Опишите достаточно подробно своё решение проблемы, и это поможет другим людям, кто столкнётся с такой же задачей.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в ответе к вашему вопросу. Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил эту проблему с помощью программы FastStone Capture. Там можно делать скриншоты с прокрутками. "Захват окна с прокруткой". Редактировать и сохранять в нужный вам формат.